# Converting html to excel in Python

Tags: python, html, excel, csv

I'm trying to convert the table in the following site to an xls table:

http://www.dekel.co.il/madad-lazarchan

The following is the code I came up with from researching:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
import csv

url='http://www.dekel.co.il/madad-lazarchan'
table = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, attrs={"class" : "medadimborder"})

print table</code>
```

How can I get it to display the headers properly and output to a csv or xls file?

If I add the following:

```
table.to_csv('test.csv')
```

instead of the print row I get this error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Thanks in Advance!

Okay based on the comments maybe I shouldn't use panda or read_html as I want a table and not a list. I wrote the following code but now the printout has delimiters and looks like I lost the header row. Also still not sure how to export it to csv file.

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
    import urllib2 
    import csv
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.dekel.co.il/madad-lazarchan').read(), 'html') 
    data = []
    table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class" : "medadimborder"}) 
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.findAll('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        print cols`

[u'01/16', u'130.7915', u'122.4640', u'117.9807', u'112.2557', u'105.8017', u'100.5720', u'98.6']
[u'12/15', u'131.4547', u'123.0850', u'118.5790', u'112.8249', u'106.3383', u'101.0820', u'99.1']
[u'11/15', u'131.5874', u'123.2092', u'118.6986', u'112.9387', u'106.4456', u'101.1840', u'99.2']

Answer (score 1):

You can use python packages available to work with Excel files. here is a [list](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Comment: That link has openpyxl at the top of the list, if you want to easily get your html tables into openpyxl, you can use tablepyxl https://github.com/martsberger/tablepyxl

Answer (score 1):

pandas.read_html returns a list of DataFrames instead of a single one. You have to specify the index of the DataFrame in the returned list (index = 0 in this case):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

```
#now the result of read_html will be named 'tables', which is a list of DataFrames
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, attrs={"class" : "medadimborder"})
#assigning the first element of the list of DataFrames 'tables' into DataFrame 'table'
table = tables[0]
#converting into csv
table.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your "table" variable is not a pandas dataframe but instead a 2D list whose first and only element is the pandas dataframe. Logically, calling pandas methods on a python list won't work and raises an `AttributeError`.
Python's built-in `type()` and `dir()` reveal this:

```
>>> type(table)
<class 'list'>

>>> type(table[0])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

# no error 
>>> table[0].to_csv('test.csv')
>>> 

# 2D to 1D list 
>>> table = table[0]
>>> table.to_csv('test.csv')
>>>
```

Comment: Updated initial question to show new code without panda, as I want a table and not a list.